# Python Execution Order with GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, execution

I'm having some issues with the following code. This is the first time that I'm working with a GUI and it's been a while since I've worked with python as well. When I try to execute the solfield function with the button, it yields no output.

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

master = Tk()

n = float()
I = float()


def solfield():
    pass



label_coils = Label(text='Number of Coils Per Meter', textvariable=n)
label_coils.grid()
coils = Entry(master)
coils.grid()

label_current = Label(text='Current in Amps', textvariable=I)
label_current.grid()
current = Entry(master)
current.grid()

calculate_button = Button(text='Calculate', command=solfield())
calculate_button.grid()
label_bfield = Label(text='B Field in +z Direction')
label_bfield.grid()
label_result = Label(text='solfield')
label_result.grid()


master.title('Coil Gun Simulation')
master.mainloop()


def solfield():
    mu0 = math.pi*4e-7
    solfield = mu0*n*I
    print solfield
```

Any other tips would be appreciated as well, as there will eventually be much more coding for me to do.

This has been solved. If anyone is interested, here is the code after several fixes were made:

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

master = Tk()

label_coils = Label(text='Number of Coils Per Meter')
label_coils.grid()
coils = Entry(master)
coils.grid()

label_current = Label(text='Current in Amps')
label_current.grid()
current = Entry(master)
current.grid()



def solfield():
    mu0 = math.pi*4e-7
    n = float(coils.get())
    I = float(current.get())
    fieldmag = mu0*n*I
    print fieldmag

calculate_button = Button(text='Calculate', command=solfield)
calculate_button.grid()
label_bfield = Label(text='B Field in +z Direction')
label_bfield.grid()
label_result = Label(text='solfield')
label_result.grid()



master.title('Coil Gun Simulation')
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use a different variable name than `solfield` in your `solfield` function.  That is likely to give you problems.

Comment: As a side note, `n = float()` is the same as `n = 0.0`, and there's really no good reason to do it in the first place. I don't think you want a global variable for this. If you do, you probably don't want it to be 0 (otherwise `solfield()` will always print `0`…). So, presumably you're going to set a "real value" at some point. If so, you don't need to set it to `float()` first and then later set it to the real value. Python doesn't require you to "declare variables at the top" like C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
calculate_button = Button(text='Calculate', command=solfield())
```

To pass the function `solfield` itself as the `command`, just use its name:

```
calculate_button = Button(text='Calculate', command=solfield)
```

What you're doing is *calling* the function, and then passing the return value of that function as the command.

Since you defined `solfield` above as do-nothing function, that return value is `None`, so you're telling `calculate_button` that its `command=None`, and it's properly doing nothing.

---

Meanwhile, as SethMMorton pointed out (but then deleted):

> You have two functions named `solfield`, and you are naming a variable `solfield` in one of your `solfield` functions. Remove the empty function (the one with pass), and using a different variable name in the remaining function.

This isn't causing your actual problem, but it's certainly adding to the confusion that makes it harder for you to *find* the problem. (For example, if you hadn't included the excess empty definition of `solfield` at all, you would have gotten a `NameError` in the incorrect line, which would have made things easier to debug.)

---

Putting it all together, what you should do is:

1. Get rid of the empty (`pass`-only) definition of `solfield`.
2. Move the real implementation of `solfield` up above the point where you build the GUI.
3. Don't name a local variable `solfield` within the function.
4. Pass just `solfield`, not `solfield()` as the `command` for `calculate_button`.

Comment: That's part of the problem. The other part is that they don't define `solfield` until after tha mainloop exits.

Comment: He defined `solfield` *after* he used it.  It is likely he thought he needed a function declaration like in `C`.  I think that moving the definition to where the "declaration" is will help.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Sorry, I was rapidly rewriting my answer to get all of Seth's points into my answer (since he deleted both his comment and is answer, but they were important). Does the current version look good?

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for adding my deleted response.  After I posted it I realized it wasn't the root cause, but you had already posted the correct answer and I thought it's best not to water down the wine.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Finally fixed all of my issued for this bit of code after I noticed my mistakes with trying to work with the labels in the calculation instead of the actual entries.